# How to connect a wifi with SSID and password in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

is it possible to make an application connect to a wifi in wp8, provided that the app knows the Name/SSID and password.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no API to manage network connections. For security reason.